# how to use application delegate method in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, label, uiapplicationdelegate

i have try the label value pass one view to another view .i have use the table view and table view put a label . code......

such as

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %i",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];


    UITableViewCell *cell =[self.tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
 {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

  NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[finalArray objectAtIndex:indexForAll]];
  NSLog(@"-=-=  arr count %d  -=-====",[arr count]);
  NSLog(@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description]);
   NSLog(@"-======  row  value  %d -=======",indexPath.row);

NSLog(@"--=-=--- strike value %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"Strike"]);

//indexForAll=indexPath.row

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

cell.highlighted = YES;

 NSMutableArray *arr2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@" -=-=-=-= Arr2 value : %d ",[arr2 count]);

 NSLog(@"%@",[arr2 description]);

//.......................................Strike value.....................................//
  UILabel *label1;
  label1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3,50, 15)]; 

  NSLog(@"-=-=--= lable1  value  -%@",[[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Strike"]);

[label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
  [[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Strike"]]];

  label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

  [label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

  [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

  [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

  NSLog(@"lable1 addded");

  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

i have want to label1 value fetch another view.i have trid but even not success .if any helped 
thanks

i have tried
such

```
AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

but value not pass.

Comment: Use 4 spaces to indent your code, this is unreadable.

Comment: well structured code may help to understand the question better

Comment: Your way of describing question is not proper.improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Nstring type property in appDeleagate suppose NSString *labelText;

and now

```
AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

In this class where you set this property.

Now before this line

--->[label1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Strike"]]];

set that property of appDelegate.
appDelegate.labelText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Strike"]];
```

And now where you want to use this property make object of appDelegate and access this property by using . operator.

This will definately help you if you implement in correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Code for CurrentViewControllerHavingTableView

Hi try making a property of your UILabel and synthesize it in the .m file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *label1;

@synthesize label1;

Now make an object of your current view in the calling class like this


Code for Calling Class

CurrentViewControllerHavingTableView *viewController = [[CurrentViewControllerHavingTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentViewControllerHavingTableView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

Make a UILabel *label2;

label2.textlabel.text=viewController.label1.textlabel.text;
```

This will surely work for you.